Showing coplanar vectors are also colinear
I have a question regarding this problem: if vectors $\vec a \times \vec b,\vec b \times \vec c,\vec c \times \vec a$ are coplanar, then they are also colinear.
I visually understand this, but don't really know how to prove it. The obvious starting point from where I could derive something useful is by expanding the expression of the triple product since coplanar implies $(\vec a \times \vec b,\vec b \times \vec c,\vec c \times \vec a)=0$, but then I get stuck on calucaltions or this might not even be the right idea to start with.
Thanks for the help!

If $a,b,c$ are coplanar, then clearly their cross products are collinear and we are done. So assume they aren’t coplanar.
Say there are $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$
x(a\times b)+y(b\times c)+z(c\times a) = 0.
$$
Taking the dot product with $c$ gives
$$
x [c\cdot(a\times b)] = 0.
$$
Since we assumed that $a,b,c$ are not coplanar, we get $x=0$. Similarly, we get $y=z=0$. This means the cross products are not coplanar.
Therefore, if the cross products are coplanar, then the original vectors must be coplanar, which means the cross products must be collinear.

If $\vec a \times \vec b,\vec b \times \vec c,\vec c \times \vec a$ be coplanar, then their scalar triple product is $0$.
i.e.$\left[\vec a \times \vec b\hspace{0.5cm}\vec b \times \vec c\hspace{0.5cm}\vec c \times \vec a\right]=0$
Also,$\left[\vec a \times \vec b\hspace{0.5cm}\vec b \times \vec c\hspace{0.5cm}\vec c \times \vec a\right]=\left[\vec a\hspace{0.5cm}\vec b\hspace{0.5cm}\vec c\right]^2$
Thus, $\left[\vec a\hspace{0.5cm}\vec b\hspace{0.5cm}\vec c\right]^2=0$
So $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ are coplanar.
$\Rightarrow \vec c=\lambda\vec a+\mu\vec b$
Taking cross-product with $\vec a$ and then with $\vec b$ on both sides
$\Rightarrow \vec c\times\vec a=\mu(\vec b\times \vec a)\Rightarrow \vec c\times \vec a$ and $\vec a\times\vec b$ are collinear
$\Rightarrow \vec c\times\vec b=\lambda(\vec a\times \vec b)\Rightarrow \vec b\times \vec c$ and $\vec a\times\vec b$ are collinear
$\Rightarrow \vec c\times \vec a$ , $\vec a\times\vec b$ and $\vec b\times \vec c$ are collinear
So if $ \vec c\times \vec a$ , $\vec a\times\vec b$ and $\vec b\times \vec c$ are coplanar then they must be collinear as well.
